# how to set a fill suffix?

Tags: fill-paragraph

I want to fill (wrap) long lines at *n* characters, ensuring that each new line ends with "///". (That is the "continuation character" for long lines in Stata code.

So that something like this

```
This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line.
```

would be broken up into something like this

```
This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This ///
  is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line.
```

(where the first line, along with the /// is no more than *n* characters.

I see info about *prefixes* in the fill section of the manual, but nothing about suffixes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's very little support for it in Emacs's standard infrastructure, sadly.
You can try using something like:

```
(add-function :around (local 'comment-line-break-function)
  #'my-insert-triple-slash-at-eol)
(defun my-insert-triple-slash-at-eol (orig-fun &rest args)
  (insert "///")
  (apply orig-fun args))
```

Comment: Really appreciate this, Stefan. Thanks! Can you give me a bit more guidance on how to implement your solution. I have evaled that code (without error!), but am not sure how to call the function when I have text that I want it to fill and add the /// at the end of the line. I am sorry for my ignorance, and thanks again!

Comment: @Cheuk: I think it will only affect `auto-fill-mode`.